# How to make other elements slide rather than jump out of the way for a slide-in element?

Tags: jquery

I have a little toolbar of icons at the top of my web-app. One of them, when clicked, slides out a horizontal slider to control image brightness. But the other icons to the right of it jump out of the way to make room for the slider which slides into view, and then jump back when it's slid back out of sight.

How can I make the other icons slide with it to make space, instead of jumping?

```
    $('#contrastSlider').slider();
    $('#contrast').click(function() {
        $('#contrastSlider').toggle("slide", 300);
    });
```

(The icons are all divs, float:left'ed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with animate:

```
$('#contrast').click(function() {
    $('#contrastSlider').animate({left: $('heredivid').width()}, 300);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered defining them with a `class` rather than an `id`?

For example:

```
<div class ="slider">stuff</div>
<div class ="slider">more stuff</div>
```

etc...

The when you click on one of the div's, your slider can be called by:

```
$('.slider').toggle("slide", 300);
```